# How to solve a "Misplaced \omit" error in a table?

Tags: tables, subfloats, multicolumn

I'm trying to code table in LaTeX; however, the following code isn't working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a4} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
        $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
            \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
            \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep-\pgflinewidth},
            minimum  height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight-\pgflinewidth] (box) {};
            \draw[line cap=round] (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
            \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
            \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
            \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}


\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{color}

%\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\newcommand{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}


\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]

    \caption{View} 
    \label{ch:a:3:4:2:1}
    \centering

    \subfloat[VR]{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
            \hline
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \diag{.1em}{4.5cm}{\textbf{Views}}{\textbf{QP}} & 20& 26& 32& 38& 44                    \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
            \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_{6}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.2 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_{7}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.9 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.5 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_{8}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.7 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.1 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{88.8 $dB$} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 

        \end{tabular}
    }


    \subfloat[VS]{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
            \hline
            \hline

            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \diag{.1em}{4.5cm}{\textbf{Views}}{\textbf{QP}} & 20& 26& 32& 38& 44                      \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
            \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_{6}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{37.1 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{55.6 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{55.5 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{33.6 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31.3 $dB$} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_{7}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{36.4 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{55.1 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{55.2 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{33.5 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{31.3 $dB$} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_{8}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{36.9 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{55.4 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{55.1 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{33.1 $dB$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{30.8 $dB$} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-7}


        \end{tabular}
    }

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and the error output is:

```
Misplaced \omit.

\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan
```

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem? For example, where is `\diag` from? You need to start this MWE with `\documentclass` and it should end with `\end{document}`. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the problem you're experiencing. That's not the case as of now...

Comment: In particular, please be indicate which packages define the macros `\subfloat` and `\diag`.

Comment: All packeges that i added on the file:

Comment: Could you draw a little picture of the desired result? This code is a big mix of different packages. Thank you!

Comment: Table is presented as I want. Nothing is wrong. However, compiler gives an error (\omit), which makes so annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two `\multicolum`s in your first cell. Remove the empty one and change your diagonal line to:

```
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
    \multicolumn{2}{p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep % not the 2
    ...
```

The table however looks not correct to me, but as you said in comment, it is right for you...

---

If you want to use `booktabs`, you should stick to its design and not use vertical lines or this diagonal line you try to use.

In the following, I rewrote the complete table, in order to get it nice with `booktabs`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % replacing the old package a4
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}   
        \caption{View}\label{ch:a:3:4:2:1}
        \centering
        \subfloat[][VR]{
        \begin{tabular}{c*{5}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Views}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{QP}} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-6}
            & {$20$} & {$26$} & {$32$} & {$38$} & {$44$} \\ \midrule
            $V_{6}/\si{\decibel}$ & 88.8 & 88.8 & 88.2 & 88.8 & 88.8 \\ 
            $V_{7}/\si{\decibel}$ & 88.9 & 88.8 & 88.5 & 88.8 & 88.8 \\ 
            $V_{8}/\si{\decibel}$ & 88.7 & 88.8 & 88.1 & 88.8 & 88.8 \\ \bottomrule             
        \end{tabular}}

        \subfloat[][VS]{
        \begin{tabular}{c*{5}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Views}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{QP}} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-6}
            & {$20$} & {$26$} & {$32$} & {$38$} & {$44$} \\ \midrule
            $V_{6}/\si{\decibel}$ & 37.1 & 55.6 & 55.5 & 33.6 & 33.3 \\ 
            $V_{7}/\si{\decibel}$ & 36.4 & 55.1 & 55.2 & 33.5 & 31.3 \\ 
            $V_{8}/\si{\decibel}$ & 36.9 & 55.4 & 55.1 & 33.1 &30.8 \\ \bottomrule          
        \end{tabular}}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. It works fine, and produces a good table.

Comment: @Cagri Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Comment: I really like the first example that you ploted. However, I would like to add \subfloat , and present them side-by-side. Could you help me about it?

Comment: @Cagri Just remove the blank line between the two subfloats (or replace it by `\hfil` or any other horizontal distance). Depending on your page settings, you will have to reduce font size or column separation or something else.